# Let $f$ a function with bounded partial derivatives. Find the greatest value that $f$ can achieve at point $(1, 2)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function partial differentiable with \begin{align*}
 \left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \,  (x, y) \right| \leq 10 \, \, \, \,  \text{and} \, \, \, \left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \, (x, y) \right| \leq 20
\end{align*}
for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and with $f(0, 0) = 0$. Find the greatest value that $f$ can achieve at the point $(1, 2)$.
Give an example of a function $f$ satisfying these assumptions and such that $f(1, 2)$ achieve this value.

I have really no idea to solve this problem (maybe with Taylor's theorem but I don't know how). I only know that a function $f$ satisfying these assumptions is continuous and $L$-lipschitz with $L:=10 \sqrt5$ but I don't see anything else. Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two line integrals: first along x-axis, then parallel to y-axis. That is,

$$|f(x,y)|\leq f(0,0)+|\int_0^{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, 0) dx|+|\int_0^{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (1, y) dy|$$
$$\leq 1\cdot 10+2\cdot20=50$$

Conversely $f(x,y)=10x+20y$ makes this bound sharp.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!